# database connection

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection

I created an interface a.xml that contains 2 EditText and a file code.java  (containing the java code).
I want to link my code and the interface with a SQLite Database

The database contains a single table
the table contains 2 columns

how to make the connection to the database and execute a SQL query (Select) (the contents of DBHelper?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the basics here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Also see the linked demo: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html